# $g(x) = 0$ if $f(x)$ is rational measurability

Tags: measure-theory

Say $f$ is a measurable real-valued function on $X$, and put $g(x) = 0$ if $f(x)$ is rational and $g(x)=1$ if $f(x)$ is irrational. Is $g$ measurable?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The Dirichlet function *is* in fact measurable (it is Borel). Note that the composition of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: can you expand a little more please?

Comment: @niels: $g$ is the composition of the Dirichlet function with your $f$.